# Cannot connect to server "localhost"?

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I've been developing web apps for several months now on my mac using the built in apache server and everything has been fine. I restarted my mac this morning and now when I try to connect to anything on localhost I get the error: "Could not connect to localhost". Here are some things I have already checked:

- Apache is running. System Preferences->Sharing->Web Sharing is turned on.
- I ran "apachectl configtest" and it returned "Syntax OK"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you ping localhost and what is ib console(as an admin user)?

Comment: 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms

Comment: Is this something you ever figured out or are you still in need of help in answering?

Comment: I actually no longer use the machine in question, so I don't need assistance any longer.

Answer (score 2):

From the terminal `curl http://localhost || echo $?` might be a good place to start to determine if this is a resource issue, routing issue or apache issue.

You'll either get back a valid http response or an error that may lead the way to knowing why your other web clients are not connecting to localhost on port 80.

Answer (score -3):

I can recommend [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). It's everything you need in one software-package. Apache, MySQL and PHP. I use it for years and I never met a problem!

Comment: This says nothing about the question

Comment: No true, but it will solve Groppe's issue never the less...

Comment: Why - as apache is still here and runs with firewalls in exactly the same way