# Localhost Forbidden

Tags: macos, permission, apache

I've read many posts and articles on how to fix this but I'm at a loss as to why nothing I try is working!

I have a number of vhosts setup in my document root which are working fine but for some reason I can't get access to localhost itself, permissions look ok to me i.e. _www has full access to document root and all subfolders

Below is an excerpt from my https.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/cduve/sites"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Users/cduve/sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And a screenshot of the finder info for "/Users/cduve/sites":

[image]

Comment: What is the permission on the parent folder `/Users/cduve/` ??

Comment: Oh -- and, you probably need "Sites" instead of "sites" in the apache config files.  If that works, let me know, and I'll put it in the answer section below.

Comment: @Kent Tried 'Sites' but no joy, funny thing is the  vhosts are subdirectories of sites and they work fine but if I try to access them with localhost/vhost1 etc. it's forbidden... Permissions for cduve are rw for cduve r for staff and no access everyone

Comment: In order to see the subdirectories, then _www (or one of its groups) must also be able to read from the parent directory.  The easiest way would be to give everyone read permission of /Users/cduve

Comment: @Kent Yeah I'll try that now but I'm a bit confused because the vhosts are subdirectories and they work fine!

Comment: @Kent Unfortunately it didn't work!

Comment: Well, now I'm stumped.  What happens if you make a simple file in /Users/cduve/test.html and try to access `localhost/test.html` with the browser?

Comment: @Kent since localhost is set to /Users/cduve/Sites, I'm assuming you meant create /Users/cduve/Sites/test.html I tried that but still forbidden... If I put the same file in one of the subdirectories e.g. Sites/testsite/test.html no problem! The vhost is set to local.testsite.com which points to Sites/testsite

Comment: How about when you use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: @deesbek Same thing...

Comment: oki mate, what web server are you running, what os 10.7, 10.8? on a mini, MBP? I would be keen to test and help you.

Comment: @Deesbek Thanks man appreciate it! I'm running 10.9 on MBP

Comment: ... and the webserver? Apache? Tomcat? versions? how was it set up?

Comment: I would also have a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41185/10733 and post the output

Comment: @Deesbek Apache I followed this [guide] (http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-osx-109-mavericks) to set it up. Output from terminal was `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.</p>
</body></html>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11527/discussion-between-deesbek-and-doovers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this by checking the error_log file using the `tail -f` command which included the following error:

```
[client 127.0.0.1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI or unacceptable Unicode in URI: /users/cduve/sites/, wants: /Users/cduve/Sites/
```

The above error made me fix the case of the document root, the next error encountered was:internal server error so going back to the error_log:

```
[crit] [client ::1] configuration error: couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /
```

Which was solved by commenting out `Require all granted` in https.conf

The original set up was on a MBP using the following [steps](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-osx-109-mavericks).

The virtual host set up was done as per: http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/how-set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-109-mavericks-and-osx-108-mountain-lion

Comment: Just to point out here, the default error log is at `/var/log/apache2/error_log`